# Removing equidistant points from image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have this image-
[image]

I want to remove these point marked with yellow circles-
[image]

So, basically I want to remove all those points which are almost equidistant and lies almost on the same line between any given two points.

This is what I have tried.I found the equation between any two points and removed all the points which lie on that line.Here is what I have tried-

```
clc;
I=imread('untitled.png');
imshow(I);
I=im2bw(I);

L = bwlabel(I,8) ;  %Calculating connected components
mx=max(max(L));

for i=1:mx
    [r1,c1] = find(L==i);

    x1=mean(c1);
    y1=mean(r1);
    for j=1:mx
        if i~=j
            [r2,c2] = find(L==j);
            x2=mean(c2);
            y2=mean(r2);
            slope=(y2-y1)./(x2-x1);
            for k=1:mx
                [r,c] = find(L==k);
                rc = [r,c];                
                x3=mean(c);
                y3=mean(r);
                temp=((y3-y2)-(slope).*(x3-x2));
                if k~=i & k~=j
                   if temp >=-0.5 & temp <=0.5
                       for l=1:r
                           for m=1:c
                               I(l,m)=0;
                           end
                       end
                   end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
figure,imshow(I);
```

But here,it will remove all the points which lie on the line and not just equidistant points.Also, the time complexity is O(N^5),so this algorithm will not work even for small values.I even could not check my above code for the input image provided it was taking way too much time. So, is there any way I can do this?

Comment: All your "lines" seem to have the same orientation. Can we assume that this is indeed the case ?

Comment: @Ratbert No this is not always true for the images which I am working with.The orientation of lines can be different

Answer (score 0):

It's not just that your code is O(n^5), but the `find` commands in particular are very slow.

I think that you can do this easily in O(n^3), with a minimum use of `find` commands.

This would look like:

1) Generate a Nx2 array of points, reducing the image to a series of data points.

```
nPoints = max(L(:));
points = zeros(nPoints, 2);
for ix = 1:nPoints
    [r1,c1] = find(L==ix);
    points(ix,:) = [r1,c1];
end
```

That should be very fast.

2) Now, for each point, check if it is in nearly between any two other points.

```
maskRemove = false(nPoints,1);
for ixPoint = 1:nPoints
    for ixEndA = 1:nPoints
        for ixEndB = 1:(ixEndA-1)  %We don't need to check both directions
            rcCheck = points(ixPoint,:);
            rcEndA   = points(ixEndA ,:);
            rcEndB   = points(ixEndB ,:);

            %We want to see if the "check" point is near the average 
            %of the endpoints
            meanOfEnds = mean([rcEndA; rcEndB], 2);  

            %This is a MAX norm, you can use a circular distance 
            %check if you want.
            distanceFromMean = max(abs(meanOfEnds - rcCheck ) );

            %Mark the result in the results mask
            maskRemove(ixPoint)= distanceFromMean  < thresholdValue;
        end
    end
end

%Now, "maskRemove" should be a logical TRUE for any point that needs 
%to be removed.
```

Comment: I get error in this line- `points = zeros(nPoints, 2);` .It says error using zeros.Size inputs must be scalar

Comment: Still I think there is some problem with the algorithm itself.I tried this with the given input image and it makes all the points in maskRemove `1`.

Comment: What are the "distanceFromMean" values? Do they make sense?

Comment: They are quite large.most of them are above 200.hardly 5 or 6 are below that.

Comment: Also I doubt this algorithm can help in removing the points I have marked inside circles.This is because it calculates mean of all the two points for any point to be checked.

Comment: It looks like the ">" should have been "<". The "five or six" lower values are probably the values you want to remove. If you post the "points" matrix it will be easier to check.

Answer (score 0):

I think a good way to do this is doing it. It's ~O(N) with the number of circles

```
>> TimingFunction(1000, 2)
Elapsed time is 0.103834 seconds.
>> TimingFunction(1000, 4)
Elapsed time is 0.179529 seconds.
>> TimingFunction(1000, 8)
Elapsed time is 0.270225 seconds.
>> TimingFunction(1000, 16)
Elapsed time is 0.601423 seconds.
>> TimingFunction(1000, 32)
Elapsed time is 1.070139 seconds.
```

And O(N^2) with the image size (I used a square to test)

```
>> TimingFunction(500, 16)
Elapsed time is 0.139831 seconds.
>> TimingFunction(1000, 16)
Elapsed time is 0.531034 seconds.
>> TimingFunction(2000, 16)
Elapsed time is 1.974798 seconds.
```

And the function is:

```
function TimingFunction(SquareSize, NumberCircles)
%This is generating a sample "image"
I = ones(SquareSize);

%This is generating sample circles
X = randi(round(0.9*size(I, 2)), NumberCircles, 1);
Y = randi(round(0.9*size(I, 1)), NumberCircles, 1);
R = randi(round(min(size(I)) / 20), NumberCircles, 1);

%this is timing
tic
Ip = circleErase(I, X, Y, R);
toc

%Just to allow for visualization
surf(Ip)

end

%this is the actual code
function I = circleErase(I, X, Y, R)
%I is the image, if it's RGB rather than a matrix you will need to modify the last line slightly
%X is a vector of the x coordinates of the center of the circle
%Y is a vector of the y coordinates of the center of the circle
%R is a vector of the circles radii

%Assign x,y coordinates to each point
[GridX, GridY] = meshgrid(1:size(I, 2), 1:size(I, 1));

%Want points within 1 unit
Within = 1;

%Finds the points within one unit for each circle edge
closeEnough = arrayfun(@(x, y, r) abs(r - sqrt((x - GridX).^2 + (y - GridY).^2)) <= Within, X, Y, R, 'uni', 0);

%Changes from a cell array to a 3D array (using:
%   http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/35766-cell-array-into-3d-matrix)
%   then finds if points intersect with any of the circles
eraseIt = any(permute(reshape(cell2mat(closeEnough).',size(closeEnough{1}, 1),size(closeEnough{1},2),[]),[3 2 1]), 1);

%Then erases it
I(eraseIt) = 0;
end
```